# maintaining the position in recycler view after removing an item from firebase real time database not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to delete an item from  firebase Realtime database. after successful deletion recycler view position is moving to bottom.

how to stop recycler view position moving to bottom?

code snippet for deleting the item from firebase recycler view:

```
try {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query applesQuery = ref.child("Chatsdata").orderByChild("messageid").equalTo(mMsgList.get(position1).getMessageID());
    applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();

                mMsgList.remove(position1);
                notifyItemRemoved(position1);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To maintain the state of the recycler view you can use `Parcelable`.
Kindly follow the steps below to achieve this.
**(1) Make a common class (if you don't have one) and a variable postsRecyclerViewState**

```
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Common {
    public static Parcelable postsRecyclerViewState ;
}
```

**(2) Attach onScrollListener to your recyclerView**

```
  recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            Common.postsRecyclerViewState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
        }
    });
```

**(3) and When you are setting adapter to your recycler view use the below code**

```
 recyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);

               if (null != Common.postsRecyclerViewState)
               {
                   recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(Common.postsRecyclerViewState);
               }
```

In this way, you can have the preserved state of the recycler view.
**Feel free to ask if anything is unclear** and Kindly mark this as a correct answer if it helps you.

Comment: after deleting position is not moving . but while scrolling up & down deleted item is showing as overlay. :-(

Comment: can you please share some screenshots or any reference so that I can understand clearrly?